# PaintEvent Memory Leaking

Tags: c#, winforms, memory, paint, memory-leaks

I am currently using the paint event on a form to draw an image onto the screen. (Think a background image) and some rectangles on top of this image.

```
 private void MainWindow_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(m_Directory + @"\Images\" + BackgroundText), m_Screen);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BGBrush, new Rectangle(X, Y, Width, Height));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Settings.TextFont, Other.Settings.TextBrush, new Rectangle(X, Y + 2, Width, Height));
 }
```

The page is being repainted very often (almost on every mouse move event) and is causing huge amounts of memory to be used. Getting to 1,500,000k before it stops drawing to the form and displays the white background with red cross on the picture for a failed paint.

I am at a slight loss as to how it is running off so badly. I am new to drawing with the paint event so any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Try creating your image in another part of your program instead of the Paint Event. Also where is Gobj created at, it looks like a Graphics object. Why not use the PaintEventArgs Graphics object instead.

Comment: Sorry, the Gobj comes from the e.graphics but it was passed into another function. Original comment now shows it using normal e.graphics. I will try to make the image in another part thanks! Will reply later if it works!

Comment: The reason why I asked about the Graphics object, is because if you create one you should be sure to dispose of it yourself along with pens and other like objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image` is `IDisposable`, so you should execute the DrawImage call within a "using" block, to ensure the Image is disposed.

But most importantly, I would reconsider doing heavy IO operations in a Paint event. Possibly have the images loaded ahead of time, to have the Paint event only worry about drawing. You are currently loading the same image hundreds of times.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if your UI thread is being use constantly, the finalizer will be blocked.  The objects might be garbage collected, but disposeable object would be added to the finalizer queue.  The finalizer runs in the UI thread, so if your UI thread is busy, dispose wont be called.  Graphics objects usually wrap an unmanaged object and that object needs to be cleaned up with dispose().

I would manually dispose all of your graphics related objects when you are done painting.